# Flutter: offline local storage syncing with online e.g. firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, user-experience, sqflite

Is this a common/reasonable Use case? 
An app allows a user to save favorites locally so that the user doesn't need to signup.

Then the user afterwards desires to share their favorites.

Therefore favorites data needs to be synced from local to remote. The usual local storage for flutter is sqflite, and firebase/store is the remote. However, this seems cumbersome, as sql to nosql conversion is necessary.

I thought that this would be a general issue for UX etc, but I can't find any discussion of this issue? Maybe forcing the user to create an account is the most general solution?

Comment: Forcing user to create an account is easier, yes, but you will, without doubt, lose a good portion of users at this step of the funnel. Maybe they'd have liked your app, who knows? It's a pity they're not coming back. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a common understanding that if you don't have **user account** then you can't have any user data associated with your name. You don't have to force the user to have an account or lock them out.

When they favourite something just show a dialog telling them "If you don't have an account your favourites are stored on the device only. If you want your favourites to be available everywhere please create an account" then show options for "Create account" or "No, Thanks"

**Create account:** Goes to account creation page

**No, Thanks:** Adds the device to the favourites list and lets the user continue to do what your app does.

There's no problem to solve here from what I'm seeing. If you don't have an account you don't get account functionality. If you track users without them entering anything it's also a little bit illegal and creepy so no need to push the limits on how you can track  the same user.

Another way to think of it is to make signup so easy they don't mind and also guarantee that it's worth it. Won't be used for spam or information selling. Take what's app as an example, even though you need to mobile number to send the messages, it's just used as a unique identifier and has nothing to do with the device's number.

Ask for their phone number or email or just any email, you'll most likely get fake info.

And what does your analytics say? Are you getting requests from users saying they lost all their information on a different device? How many people are using your favourite functionality?

Comment: Thanks, useful comments.
Not sure what you're saying about Whatsapp model - "Ask for their phone number or email or just any email, you'll most likely get fake info." What do you recommend?

Comment: There's nothing else too recommend, it's either phone number or email. But I don't think there are users that would expect their data to be moved between devices if they don't have an account so you don't have much to worry about there. Users have patterns, we build apps to satisfy those patterns. Just keep a local list of favourites and remind them everytime that it won't be stored on your server.

Comment: Ok, but the second part of my question: store locally in sqflite and then convert it to nosql in firebase? Is there a more direct way?

Comment: I don't see exactly the sqflite to nosql cumbersome conversion. I don't know where this would be happening on a consistent bases, meaning you writing the code for it at every point. This should happen "automatically" in your code since you'll be dealing with a persistence service that converts your models to what you need. You as the developer will just be dealing with transactions and MutableData using your app defined models. Could you maybe add the cumbersome code, or pseudo code to explain or demonstrate what you mean. I might be missing your point.

Answer (score 1):

I may have come to the party a little late here but here's my 2 cents worth.

The Sql to NoSql conversion is not cumbersome. In fact, there is a reasonable use case for this. I have the same requirement for an app that I am about to build.

Anyway, to store data in `RDMDB` or `NoSQLDB` you will need a data `model` to ensure consistency in your app. If the user has been using the app offline, and they later choose to go online, you can allow them to create the `Remote Account`, then check if they have `local` favorites. If they do, you will HAVE to ask them if they'd like to import them into the `remote` storage. If they choose to do so, you will then have to `read` their favorites from the `local` storage and store them in a `List<Model>` then `map()` that back to the `online` storage.

`NoSqlDB` can accept the `json` type data, so your `model` should include the conversion `fromMap()` and `toJson()` for this purpose (and others).

When I have come around to doing this, I will share my code (if I remember to come back here).

Comment: Thanks! I also remembered to come back here after 3 years to thank the previous contributors too ;)